# How can I grab a data attribute via php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a button with the data-id `3`. I want now in my mySQL database request to mark the option, that has the value `3` as selected.

```
<button data-id="3"></button>  

 <?php
    $pdo = $db->query('SELECT * FROM members ORDER BY id ASC;');
    while ($row = $pdo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       echo "<option value=".$row['id'].">".$row['name']."</option>";
    }                             
 ?>
```

So I think about something like

```
  echo "<option value=".$row['id'].";
  if ($row['id'] == data-id) {echo "selected";}
  echo ">".$row['name']."</option>";
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @u_mulder So this means, it is not possible

Comment: Where does `data-id` value come from?

Comment: Well, I send data from a table to a modal via data attributes. If I click on an edit button, then an editor opens in a bootstrap modal. If it is not possible I need to think about a different way

Comment: @Jarla but you answered on your question yourself :) Just use your echo - something like: `echo "<option value=".$row['id']." " . ($row['id'] == 3 ? "selected" : "") . ">".$row['name']."</option>";`

Comment: If you know value of `data-id` on serverside (it is stored in a php variable?) then you can compare.

Comment: No I do not know the value. It will be stored in the data attribute depending on what table row the user clicks.

Comment: @Jarla then you need set selected from client-side via JavaScript by click event.

Comment: I mean it is true, I create it like this in my loop `data-id='".$row['id']."'` which is creating the table. But the modal I have only once, and data is sent to the modal, depending on what row the user clicks

Comment: @VladimirGilevich Ok, I will check this out!